# Get variable values in HTML from the Hogan-express module

Tags: node.js, express

js and express.js, i am trying to get a title value in my HTML from an Express-hogan template but i am not getting the required output on my HTML element,i ran the app.js in node and (running on localhost-port:3000)on the browser ,here is the code for express(app.js):

```
var express = require('express'),
    app = express(),
    path = require('path');

app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));

app.engine('html', require('hogan-express'));
app.set('view engine', 'html');
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.route('/').get(function(req, res, next) {
    res.render('index', {
        title: 'Welcome to chatKat'
    });

})
app.listen(3000, function() {

    console.log('chatKat running on por t 3000');
```

Following is my html view:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title>{{title}}</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div class="hm-container">
         <h1 class="hm-title">My face book login</h1>
         <a href="#"><img src="images/facebook26.png"></a>  
         </h1>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

And the package.json:

```
{
"name": "chatkat",
"version": "1.0.0",
"description": "",
"main": "index.js",
"dependencies": {
"express": "^4.13.4",
"hogan-express": "^0.5.2",
"passport": "^0.2.0",
"passport-facebook": "^1.0.3",
"qr-image": "^3.1.0",
"socket.io": "^1.4.4"
},
"devDependencies": {
"express": "~4.2.0",
"hogan-express": "~0.5.2"
},
"scripts": {
"test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
},
"author": "",
"license": "ISC"
}
```